# Problem with [Authenticate] filter and Validator execute priority

Tags: c#, servicestack

Good Day,

I have validations with session values into a validator, if the session is expired, It has not been detected within the execution of the validator, and this validator responds with an error, a not real error.

How to change the priority of execution of [Authenticate] filter, so that the execution of this filter is before the validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the `[Authenticate]` attribute is a request filter attribute which should be applied on the service implementation whilst all the [declarative validation attributes](https://docs.servicestack.net/declarative-validation) should be applied on the Request DTO.

Since you’re already using validation attributes you should use the `[ValidateIsAuthenticated]` [type validator](https://docs.servicestack.net/declarative-validation#type-validators) to validate the user is authenticated.

Comment: For example would it look like this?:
`c#
    [ValidateIsAuthenticated]<br>
    public class TestValidator: AbstractValidator<Test>
{

}
`

Comment: @CarlosRamírez No, please read the docs, they should only be on the request DTO